# How to aligned text in graffito to the left?

Tags: horizontal-alignment

I'm using graffito for sidenotes in my thesis, is there a way to align all text to the left? (currently a comment on the left side of the page is aligned to the right for some reason...)

**Graffito** is part of **[classicthesis](https://bitbucket.org/amiede/classicthesis/wiki/Home)** and [defined](https://bitbucket.org/amiede/classicthesis/src/a58e74ecd009ab45d7d5f47cca6539fbca0f8255/classicthesis.sty?at=master) as:

```
\def\graffito@setup{%
   \slshape\footnotesize%
   \parindent=0pt \lineskip=0pt \lineskiplimit=0pt %
   \tolerance=2000 \hyphenpenalty=300 \exhyphenpenalty=300%
   \doublehyphendemerits=100000%
   \finalhyphendemerits=\doublehyphendemerits}
```

Comment: What is `graffito`? Are you using TeX or friends (LaTeX, ConTeXt) for your thesis?

Comment: Sorry, edited the question to explain what graffito is and how it is defined.

Comment: @renton14 Please edit your question and add a little *complete* test document  allowing us to reproduce the problem mentioned. Otherwise all we can do is to guess and little effective help can be provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The behavior is defined in classicthesis.sty. In most recent versions graffito is just an alias for marginpar. But if you're still using exclusively graffito, you should redefine it, after classicthesis-config.tex has been loaded as

```
\renewcommand{\graffito}[1]{\oldmarginpar%
 [\graffito@setup\raggedright\hspace{0pt}{#1}]%
 {\graffito@setup\raggedright\hspace{0pt}{#1}}}
```